# How to use JScrollpane plugin with Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have trying to build a custom scrollBar using jScrollPane for the autocomplete box.

I have tried many options available in stackoverflow, But none of them seems to be working.

Let me know if there is a way to implement the same.

I have tried below code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sJL89/13/

`var api,autocomplete_init = false;
 $("#countries").autocomplete({
    source: countryList,
    open: function(){
            if(!autocomplete_init){
                $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('scroll-pane');
            api = $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane().data('jsp');
                autocomplete_init = true;
           } else {
                api.reinitialise();
           }
        },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').jScrollPaneRemove();
    }
});

});`

Comment: Only for the 1st time the scrollbar is coming up.On next keypress scroll bar is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Scrollbar plugin

```
$("#countries").autocomplete({
    "focus": function(){
        var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element;
        var focused = menu.find("li:has(a.ui-state-focus)");
        if(menu.parent().hasClass('scroll-wrapper')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var height = menu.parent().height();
                if(focused.position().top + focused.height() > height){
                    menu.scrollTop(menu.scrollTop() + parseInt(focused.position().top) + focused.height() - height);
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    },
    "open": function(){
        var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element;
        menu.addClass('scrollbar-dynamic').addClass('autocomplete-scroll').scrollbar();
    },
    "source": countryList
});
```

jsFiddle preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/B6U6k/9/

Scrollbar custom designs & documentation available on https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar

You may notice that IE shows horizontal scrollbar when selecting item from autocomplete list. This happens because of IE renderer bug and jQuery UI CSS for selected item: 1px border + margin: -1px (which should shift element back to fix border offset). I think IE does not apply this margin. So, get rid of horizontal scrollbar with css, or get rid of border for selected item.